# how to display photos from a folder in C# (updated real-time)

Tags: c#, video, display

I have a camera and I want to use C# to real-time display the object taken by the camera. In C# program I use a C-based .exe to retrieve images from the camera to one fixed folder in my computer, and then try to display and update the image (like a live video). My problem:
(1) how to update photo viewer smoothly in C# (I hate refreshing the interface) or shall I make those photos into a video first?
(2)as the pics in the folder are real-time updated, how could I make sure the sequence of playing, or avoid conflicting? I plan to keep only 10 images, and the 11th image retrieved will replace the 1st image..., I am not very clear about that...

Thanks for the reading, sorry I might have very silly questions above...

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-develop-c-camera-video)

Comment: Look at http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Capture-Image-Photo-from-Web-Camera-Webcam-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: You can use timer and interval for changing Image content

Comment: hi, please be more specific about timer and interval, the problem is that .exe will continuously and independently retrieve the image. so in C# how to set timer and interval? thanks